# How to cancel heads-up notifications in Android 5.1

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to make an app that cancels all notifications (including heads-up notifications).

I am using a NotificationListenerService to listen for incoming notifications and when a notification is posted I use NotificationListenerService.cancelAllNotifications()

It works well on the Android  5.1.1 emulator but it fails on a Samsung with Android 5.1.1

On the Samsung phone NotificationListenerService.onNotificationPosted() is triggered, but NotificationListenerService.cancelAllNotifications() doesn't cancel heads-up notifications.

NotificationManager.cancelAll() doesn't work either

Here is my code:

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){               

this.cancelAllNotifications();

NotificationManager notification_manager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notification_manager.cancelAll();}
```

}